# Help wiring Bathroom fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I am not 100% sure how to wire my new bathroom fan, and I am looking for a little guidance. (This is for a NuTone QTN130LE1)

Here are the existing wires in the attic. I have a white wire, a black wire, and a ground.

[image: Existing house wiring]

Here is the wires for the unit:

[image: Unit Wiring]

There are taped into pairs

- First pair is White and Black
- Second pair is white and Blue
- Third pair is White and Red
- Fourth is ground.

And here is the wiring guide.

[image: Wiring Guide]

I am a little confused because of the red wire for the night light (Unit has 2 lights, a fan, and a night light) but I do not plan on using the night light if that makes a difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You only have one switch?

Comment: The bathroom has 2 switches, one for the lights above the sink, and one for the fan/light. Only 1 switch controls the whole bathroom fan unit. The fan, and the lights in the fan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Connect the black wire from the ceiling, to the black and blue wires from the fan/light.
- Connect the white wire from the ceiling, to the white/black and white/blue wires from the fan/light unit.
- Connect all bare/green grounding conductors.
- Cap the red and white/red wires from the fan/light unit.

When you're done, the switch will turn on both the light and fan at the same time.

Comment: Tester101. Thank you so much for the quick answer. Just wired it and it worked like a charm. This is only the second question I have ever asked here and you answered both. I wish I could donate to you! Your a life saver.

Comment: @SamPlusPlus If you want to spend some money, there's loads of good charities out there. [Ronald McDonald House Charities](http://www.rmhc.org/) is a good one, or [Children’s Cancer Research Fund](http://www.childrenscancer.org)

Comment: Tester, if you would like me to pay it forward. I will! thanks again!